# Creating a local custom host name instead of localhost?

Tags: dns, flask, localhost

Currently, my flask app runs locally on:

> http://localhost:5000/some_page

How could I create a local custom location for my app like:

> http://myappname/some_page

Sort of like a local domain name. Is this possible at all? Any pointers would be great.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order for the browser to resolve this custom name, you will need to add an alias to your [/etc/hosts file](http://linux.die.net/man/5/hosts).  It probably already contains a line about 127.0.0.1, in which case you just add your alias to the list

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain myappname
```

You can then change the server name in the app's config to make it explicitly use this name.

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'myappname:5000'
```

Only privileged programs (run as root or with sudo) can bind to low ports such as 80, so you will still have to use a high port number.

Answer (score -2):

It can be done using SERVER_NAME option in config:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'myappname:80'
```

More information here:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/