# Ngnix and docker compose - not return static files

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

This is `my docker-file.yml`

```
version: '2'
services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
      - ./logs/nginx_access.log:/var/log/nginx_access.log
      - ./logs/nginx_error.log:/var/log/nginx_error.log
      - ./src/app/static:/flask-app/src/app/static
    depends_on:
      - web

  web:
    build: ./
    command: gunicorn manage:app --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --access-logfile=logs/gunicorn_access_log.txt
    ports:
    - '8000:8000'
    volumes:
    - ./:/flask-app
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgresql://postgres:pass@localhost/flask_deploy
      REDIS_HOST: redis
      SECRET_KEY: 'BbGd3qe$dsf1'
      CONFIG_NAME: 'prod'
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
      - redis:redis
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - redis

  postgres:
    image: postgres:9.4
    volumes:
      - ./psql-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'pass'
      POSTGRES_DB: 'flask_deploy'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  redis:
    image: "redis:3.0-alpine"
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
```

And this is my `ngnix` config (`web` is name from `docker-compose` file) :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name web;

    # запись доступа и журналы ошибок в /var/log
    access_log /var/log/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx_error.log;

    location / {
        # переадресация запросов приложений на сервер gunicorn
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
    }

    location /static {
        # обрабатывать статические файлы напрямую, без пересылки в приложение
        autoindex on;
        alias /flask-app/src/app/static;
        expires 1d;
    }
}
```

And my site avaliable on `127.0.0.1` (without port). But.. I have trouble with static files. Flask `url_for` generate url like:

```
http://web:8000/static/img/do.jpg
```

And this link unavailable.

I can try this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/do.jpg
```

And i saw picture. But this picture returned by gunicorn, not ngnix :(

I am beginner in docker-compose and ngnix. Maybe, some comments about my config? Thanks!

Comment: You need to map the `static` directory inside the `nginx` container using `volumes`

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu hmm... maybe, but it didnt resolve my main problem. Look on link: `http://web:8000/static/img/do.jpg`. PATH correct, but HOST not correct. I try map static and now i has 404 code on `http://127.0.0.1/static/img/do.jpg` :((((((

Comment: because `web` is known only inside the network created by docker-compose. The url should be `http://localhost/static/img/do.jpg`. Also, exporting ports `8000` from `web`, `5432` from `postgres` and `6379` from `redis` are not required, unless you use them for debugging.

Comment: Update the answer with the latest nginx config

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu i didnt change nginx config. i only mount static directory like (`- ./src/app/static:/flask-app/src/app/static`)

Comment: O! Just a second

Comment: Then add this to the nginx config: `root /flask-app/src/app` and remove the `alias`. Follow this: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/serving-static-content/

Comment: @ConstantinGalbenu now, work, but not great..`url_for('static', filename='img/do.jpg')` generate url like `/static/img/do.jpg` and all is fine. But `url_for('static', filename='img/do.jpg', _external=True)` generate `http://web:8000/static/img/do.jpg` (not avaliable)..

Comment: you need to tell to Flask what is the real hostname

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28290207/2575224

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host:8000;
```

Full config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /flask-app/src/app;

    access_log /var/log/nginx_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx_error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host:8000;
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
    }

    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        expires 1d;
    }
}
```